# JavaFX: Updating Part property in one list updates the other

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, observablelist

New to JavaFX, be patient please.

**APPLICATION:**  Inventory management system.  There are parts, products.  Products can have associated parts.  In the adding/modifying product screen you can add parts that are associated with it from the list of all the parts available.

**ISSUE:**  All parts list updates the inventory level to that of what the associated parts inventory level updated too.  I need it to remain the same (ill handle the subtraction once this is figured out).

**RELEVANT CODE:**

```
  public class ProductDetailController implements Initializable {
....
  public static ObservableList<Part> newListForTV = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public static ObservableList<Part> exListForTV =  FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private void SetupGrids() {        
        colPartID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("partID"));
        colPartName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        colInventory.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("inStock"));
        colPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        tvExistingParts.setItems(exListForTV);

        colNewPartID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("partID"));
        colNewPartName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        colNewInventory.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("inStock"));
        colNewPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
//        
        for (Part nPartsAll : Inventory.allParts) {
            if (!newListForTV.contains(nPartsAll)) {
                newListForTV.addAll(Inventory.allParts);
            }
        }

        tvNewParts.setItems(newListForTV);
    }




public void AddPart() {
        boolean partAvailable = false;
        int selectionCheck = tvNewParts.getItems().size();

        if (selectionCheck > 0) {
            partN = tvNewParts.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();  
            partAvailable = CheckPartInventory(partN);
            if (partAvailable) {
                partEX = CheckIfContainsPart(exListForTV, partN);
                if (partEX == null) {
                    tvExistingParts.getItems().add(partN);
                    partEX = CheckIfContainsPart(exListForTV, partN);
                    if (partEX.getPartID() == partN.getPartID()) {
                        ClearInventoryOfPart(partEX);
                        partEX.setInStock(1); 
                    }
                } else {
                        partEX.setInStock(partEX.getInStock() + 1);            
                        tvExistingParts.refresh();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Boolean CheckPartInventory(Part part) {
        boolean available = false;
        int invPartInven = 0, invPartMin = 0, invPartMax = 0;
        for (Part invPart : Inventory.allParts) {
            if (invPart.getPartID() == part.getPartID()) {
               invPartInven = invPart.getInStock();
               invPartMin = invPart.getMin();
               invPartMax = invPart.getMax();

               if (invPartInven <= invPartMin || invPartInven >= invPartMax || invPartInven == 0) {
                   available = false;
               } else {
                   available = true;
               }
            }
        }
        return available;
    }

    private void CommitSaveOfProduct() {
        try {
            if (newProduct == false) {
                exListForTV.forEach(part -> {
                    Product.addAssociatedPart(part);
                });

                Inventory.updateProduct(new AssociatedProParts(Integer.parseInt(tfID.getText()), tfName.getText(), Double.parseDouble(tfPrice.getText()),Integer.parseInt(tfINV.getText()),Integer.parseInt(tfMin.getText()),Integer.parseInt(tfMax.getText()),exListForTV));
                genericClass.DisplayInformationAlert("Existing product has been successfully saved.");
                tvExistingParts.getItems().clear();
                genericClass.GoToPage(btnCancel, constants.productNavLocation, constants.productPageTitle);
            } else if (newProduct == true) {
                Inventory.addProduct(new AssociatedProParts(tfName.getText(), Double.parseDouble(tfPrice.getText()),Integer.parseInt(tfINV.getText()),Integer.parseInt(tfMin.getText()),Integer.parseInt(tfMax.getText()),exListForTV));
                genericClass.DisplayInformationAlert("New product has been successfully saved.");

                tvExistingParts.getItems().clear();
                genericClass.GoToPage(btnCancel, constants.productNavLocation, constants.productPageTitle);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            genericClass.DisplayErrorAlert("Saving Product has failed...");    
        }
    }


........


}
    public class Inventory {
    public static ObservableList<Product> allProducts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public static ObservableList<Part> associatedParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public static ObservableList<Part> allParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();;


.......

}

public class AssociatedProParts extends Product {

    public static ObservableList<Part> aParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public AssociatedProParts() {
        super(0,"",0,0,0,0);
    }

    public AssociatedProParts(int productID, String name, double price, int inStock, int min, int max, ObservableList<Part> associatedParts) {   
        super(productID, name, price, inStock, min, max);
         aParts.addAll(associatedParts);
    }

    public AssociatedProParts(String name, double price, int inStock, int min, int max, ObservableList<Part> associatedParts) {   
        super(name, price, inStock, min, max);
        aParts.addAll(associatedParts);
    }

    public void setAParts(Part part) {
        aParts.add(part);
        Inventory.associatedParts.addAll(aParts);
    }
    public ObservableList<Part> getAParts() {
        return aParts;
    }
}
```

**LASTLY:**  My problem is the newListForTV updates the inventory level to that of the exListForTV.  newListForTV needs to not change.  This is driving me nuts.  *And yes, I still need to go through and clean things up and abstract things to not be so cluttered. Right now, i just need this to work.*

Comment: I do recommend you learn more about Java naming conventions and then stick to them; your code is more complicated to read and understand than it needs to be.

Comment: I plan to clean it up when i am done figuring out how this part works.

Answer (score 0):

Though I would like to find a more efficient way.  I have managed to get this to work by adding another getter/setter to parts to account for the change in stock.